# Updating Ranorex Licence Server

Tags: ranorex

We need to update Ranorex licence server from version 5.1 to version 5.3.
What is the proper approach to not break the running tests?

I searched on the Ranorex homepage for this issue yet, without finding anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While user1982826's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30782561/1879699) is good the Ranorex support finally answered my question and I want to share their answer:

> Generally with the server upgrade the service will be reinstalled and
> restarted. Depending on how long that lasts (e.g. dependant on the
> computer), the connection on the client may time out and the test will
> break. So it would be safer to update the server, when no test is
> running.

Answer (score 3):

Normally, a simple upgrade should work, but wouldn't it be safer to upgrade the license server when no tests are running?
The best way in order to upgrade the license server is uninstalling the old version, restart the machine and install the new version. Usually, it also works if you just run the setup file without uninstalling the old version, but I prefer the uninstall -  restart - install approach.

Comment: That's how we do it for years. Even with the preceding uninstall the server upgrade usually takes not longer than 10 minutes. Usually there's a time of the day when all tests are done.
'